# MongoDB query to get top selling products

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, express-router

I have a MongoDB collection "**orders**" with document similar to such:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxx"),
    "orderNo": 0,
    "products": [
        { "product1": ["_Id": objectId("eeee"),"productName", "quantity", "price"] },
        { "product2": ["_Id": objectId("ffff"),"productName", "quantity", "price"] }
    ],
    "deliveryAddress": "addsfdfghf"
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("yyyyy"),
    "orderNo": 1,
    "products": [
        { "product1": ["_Id": objectId("dddd"),"productName", "quantity", "price"] }
    ],
    "deliveryAddress": "rwetrutytyi"
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("zzzz"),
    "orderNo": 2,
    "products": [
        { "product1": ["_Id": objectId("aaaa"), "productName", "quantity", "price"] },
        { "product2": ["_Id": objectId("bbbb"),"productName", "quantity", "price"] },
        { "product3": ["_Id": objectId("cccc"),"productName", "quantity", "price"] }
    ],
    "deliveryAddress": "rwetrutytyi"
}
```

Now I want to write a query to get top selling products using "**quantity**" property of every products.

correct values of in above document look like:

```
{
    "products": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "612baf1b89c77b25c40aa3bc"
        },
        "productID": "NPZ6I",
        "productName": "Cosentys 150ml",
        "quantity": "1",
        "expireDate": "04/20/2022",
        "price": "22200"
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "612baf1b89c77b25c40aa3bb"
        },
        "productID": "NPZ3I",
        "productName": "Asunra 400mg",
        "quantity": "2",
        "expireDate": "09/26/2021",
        "price": "13200"
    }],
    "orderNo": 9,
    "deliveryAddress": "Dhaka"
}
```

I want to return an object look like:

{
"_id": ObjectId("yyyyy"),
"productName": "String",
"productID": "String",
"totalSales" : "Number(sum of each products quantity)",
"totalEarning": "Number(sum of each product's price)"

}

Comment: Chan you share the sample correct values in above documents and expected result?

Comment: @varman Can you please check. I think now it's better.

Comment: your expected output is crear... you ur data *xxxxx, yyyyy , price* doesn't have any meaning, how can I predict? Give us a correct data